# Android OpenGL rotation matrix deformation

Tags: android, opengl-es, matrix, rotation

In my renderer, i have:

```
private float[] MATRIX_VIEW = new float[16];
private float[] MATRIX_PROJECTION = new float[16];
private float[] MATRIX_VP = new float[16];
```

in "onSurfaceChanged":

```
...
//Set projection
Matrix.orthoM(
  MATRIX_PROJECTION,0,
  -hDim,hDim,
  -vDim,vDim,
  1,100
);
//Set View
Matrix.setLookAtM(
  MATRIX_VIEW,0,
  cameraPosition[0],
  cameraPosition[1],
  cameraPosition[2],
  cameraFacing[0],
  cameraFacing[1],
  cameraFacing[2],
  cameraHook[0],
  cameraHook[1],
  cameraHOOK[2]
);
//SetView*Projection
Matrix.multiplyMM(
  MATRIX_VP,0,
  MATRIX_PROJECTION,0,
  MATRIX_VIEW,0
);
...
```

i have many clones of one shape,
so i wrote "ShapeSet_Set" class with:

```
...    
private float[] MATRIX_ORIGIN = new float[16];
private float[] MATRIX_VPO = new float[16];

private float[] MATRIX_SCALE = new float[16];
...

/*
origin matrix is group of all shapes center position
scale matrix represents zoom
*/
```

and "ShapeSet_Element" with:

```
...    
private float[] MATRIX_POSITION = new float[16];
private float[] MATRIX_ROTATION = new float[16];

private float[] MATRIX_ALL = new float[16];
...

/*
position matrix is position of shape relative to origin position
rotation matrix is shape rotation arond its center
all matrix is matrix which will be passed to shader
*/
```

In renderer's on "DrawFrame", ShapeSet_Set's "onDrawFrame" is caled.
It calculates View*Projection*Origin matrix:

```
...
Matrix.multiplyMM(
  MATRIX_VPO,0,
  RENDERER.getVPMatrix(),0,
  MATRIX_ORIGIN,0
);
...
```

and calls each ShapeSet_Element's "onDrawFrame" which contains:

```
...
//Get View*Projection*Origin matrix
System.arraycopy(
  SET.getVPOMatrix(),0,
  MATRIX_ALL,0,
  16
);
//Apply zoom
Matrix.multiplyMM(
  MATRIX_ALL,0,
  MATRIX_ALL,0,
  SET.getScaleMatrix(),0
);
//Apply element's position
Matrix.multiplyMM(
  MATRIX_ALL,0,
  MATRIX_ALL,0,
  MATRIX_POSITION,0
);
//Apply element's rotation
Matrix.multiplyMM(
  MATRIX_ALL,0,
  MATRIX_ALL,0,
  MATRIX_ROTATION,0
);
...
```

Everything works fine,until i apply rotation.
This is method to set element's rotation:

```
public void setRotation(float xDeg,float yDeg,float zDeg)
{
  //Set new rotation values to open up actual values
  rotation_X = xDeg;
  rotation_Y = yDeg;
  rotation_Z = zDeg;
  //Set new rotation matrix
  Matrix.setIdentityM(MATRIX_ROTATION,0);
  //Rotate around x axis
  Matrix.rotateM(
    MATRIX_ROTATION,0,
    rotation_X,0,
    1,0,0
  );
  //Rotate around y axis
  Matrix.rotateM(
    MATRIX_ROTATION,0,
    -rotation_Y,0,
    0,1,0
  );
  //Rotate around z axis
  Matrix.rotateM(
    MATRIX_ROTATION,0,
    rotation_Z,0,
    0,0,-1
  );
}
```

When element is rotated around x or y axis, it works fine, but...
when rotated around z axis, element's height (original y dimension) is geometricaly reduced
up to 0, when rotated 90 degrees and enlarged to original value when rotated 180 degrees.

Does anybody know, what may cause this?

I cant resolve if this is done by wrong matrix multiplication or wrong rotation matrix setting.

Comment: It's better to use quaternions when dealing with rotations involving multiple axes. Also prevents gimbal locks.

Comment: Can you be more specific, i do not now anything about this method.

Comment: Ive tried quaternions. Rotation around x and y axis works fine, abut z axis deformations remains.

Comment: Rotation around z axis is deformed even if i rotate shape only around it. Does anybody have any idea, what may cause deformation of rotation around z axis?

Answer (score 0):

can avoid gimbal lock without quaternions like this http://tutorialrandom.blogspot.com/2012/08/how-to-rotate-in-3d-using-opengl-proper.html

it sounds like something in your modelview matrix is going wrong, try doing rotations like in the above link and it may solve your problem